# Button not detecting click

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Following along with a RTS tutorial but hit a weird snag when it comes to the skill buttons that units need to have. The button is being created on screen in the correct place with the correct name (so I know everything up to AddUnitSkillButtonListener is working). But whenever I click on the button it just deselects the unit like I'd clicked somewhere else on screen. I checked to see if the issue was with _selectedUnit.TriggerSkill(), but after trying the below even "Click detected" is not being printed. I've checked my button prefab and it is interactable is there something else I'm missing?

```
      if (unit.SkillManagers.Count > 0)
    {
        GameObject g;
        Transform t;
        Button b;
        

        for (int i = 0; i < unit.SkillManagers.Count; i++)
        {
            g = Instantiate(unitSkillButtonPrefab) as GameObject;
            t = g.transform;
            b = g.GetComponent<Button>();
            unit.SkillManagers[i].SetButton(b);
            t.Find("Text").GetComponent<Text>().text = unit.SkillManagers[i].skill.skillName;
            t.SetParent(_selectedUnitActionButtonsParent);
            _AddUnitSkillButtonListener(b, i);
        }
    }
}

private void _AddUnitSkillButtonListener(Button b, int i)
{
    b.onClick.AddListener(() => print("Click detected"));//_selectedUnit.TriggerSkill(i));
}
```

Comment: Do you have an `EventSystem` in your scene? When you click on the buttons, does the color change at all or when you hover does it change? Or is there no response from the buttons at all?

Comment: There's an EventManager and the button is changing color when I hover over it. The button does not respond at all to being clicked, it just disappears (which it is supposed to if I click on anywhere else on the scene.)

Comment: Have you made sure that the snippet is being broken into? Have you added a print inside of your `for` loop to see if the function is getting called so the button gains an `onClick`?

Comment: Yes, that was the first thing I checked. _AddUnitSkillButtonListener is definitely being called as soon as a unit is selected.

Comment: When you say "it just disappears (which it is supposed to if I click on anywhere else on the scene.)", what exactly do you mean by this? The way that the UI hierarchy works is whatever is furthest down in the hierarchy will receive the click events. If you have a UI panel that closes your other UI, it must be a parent of the other buttons or else it will receive the click, not your skill buttons.

Comment: The skill buttons are part of a panel that is only set to active when a unit is selected. There's a UnitManager attached to each object that keeps track of if it's a part of the global selectedunits list. If I click anywhere but on the unit (or on another unit but holding shift) it removes that unit from the global selectedunits list.

Comment: Can you post the hierarchy for the current buttons and this panel? Edit your question with the image, might be the issue.

Comment: It would be nice to have an image of the button Hierachy. It sounds to me like you are actually clicking on somethign else than the button which causes it to hide and not beeing triggered.